# Avoid generating core file when killing child_process

Tags: node.js

I have a Node script that starts up a a `mongod` and a `node` process. I have setup a process listener in the script that listens for `SIGINT`, in case I should cancel using `Ctrl-C`. The listener then uses [`child_process#kill()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal) to kill these other two processes

This all works, but it almost always ends up generating a `core` file from the `mongod` process. I would like to avoid creating this file. How would I do this? (Yes, I do realize I can just issue a file system call to remove it).

**Output**

```
^C[mongod]  2017-07-23T09:23:07.181+0200 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 2 (Interrupt), will terminate after current cmd ends
2017-07-23T09:23:07.181+0200 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-07-23T09:23:07.181+0200 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 6
2017-07-23T09:23:07.181+0200 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 7
2017-07-23T09:23:07.181+0200 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-23451.sock
2017-07-23T09:23:07.181+0200 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-07-23T09:23:07.181+0200 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
Caught SIGINT. Exiting gracefully ...
```

Comment: What signal are you killing the processes with?

Comment: @PSkocik _"got signal 2 (Interrupt)"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `kill` syscall, you should avoid sending signals whose default action is to terminate with a a core dump (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html).

If you're not sending such signals, you can eliminate the core dump
by setting your process limit on core dumps to 0.

This is done through the `rlimit` syscall, but since NodeJs probably doesn't have an API for it, you can achieve the same result by spawning the child procesess through a shell where you can set the limit with `ulimit -c 0` (the limit is inherited by child processes).

Example:

```
const child_process = require('child_process')
const child = child_process.spawn("ulimit -c 0; sh -c 'kill -ABRT $$'; ls core", [], {shell: true });
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
child.stderr.pipe(process.stdout);
```

If you run the above with:

rm -f core; nodejs the_script.js

it should output:

```
Aborted
ls: cannot access core: No such file or directory
```

If you don't want core dumps anywhere in your nodejs-created process hierarchy, you can set `ulimit -c 0` before you start `nodejs`.